# Is is possible to make a method execute only once?

Tags: java

I have a for loop and structure like this:

```
for(....)
....
....
if(isTrue)
... do something..
.. method to be executed once (doTrick) is declared outside for loop.
....endif
endfor

public void doTrick()
...
...
..end
```

Is it possible for a method in for loop to be executed only once?

Comment: All-caps implies that it's an acronym, which it is not.

Comment: @Gandalf It's not an acronym but a name so you don't write it uppercase

Comment: hmm well we all knew what I meant so there was no difference as James say ..

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sure!..

```
if(!alreadyExecuted) {
    doTrick();
    alreadyExecuted = true;
}
```

Comment: In a multithreaded environment you might wish to synchronize that block.

Comment: Presumably though the alreadyExecuted is going to be a local variable though,

Answer (score 20):

Your can use `AtomicBoolean` to make sure the task is only called the first time:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Once {
    private final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean();
    
    public void run(Runnable task) {
        if (done.get()) return;
        if (done.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Once once = new Once();
once.run(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        foo();
    }
});

// or java 8
once.run(() -> foo());
```

Comment: `import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;`

Comment: Note that the second call of `Once.run(Runnable)` might return before the first call has finished `task.run()`.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why is a `if (done.get()) return;` check there? To my understanding of [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet(boolean,boolean)) `done.compareAndSet(false, true)` will run exactly once on transition from "false" to "true" and all consequential calls will enter the branch as it expects "false" and it is already set to "true".

Comment: A quicker solution is just `if (done.getAndSet(true)) return;  task.run();`

Comment: This is really close, but like  JojOatXGME said, we might need to prevent the OTHER threads from continuing until this is dealt with.

Answer (score 13):

if you use kotlin, you can do this:

```kotlin
val execOnce by lazy {
   print("hello, world")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Java 8, you can effectively do this using automatic memoization as described here: [Do it in Java 8: Automatic memoization](http://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization)

I'll admit that memoization could be considered overkill for a "run once" scenario, but it is a rather clean alternative to some described in previous answers.

For instance:

```
public void doSomething() { ... }

Map<Boolean, Boolean> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void doSomethingOnce() {
  cache.computeIfAbsent(true, x -> {
    doSomething();
    return true;
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not handle multithreaded use.  You would end up with multiple caches.  Marking cache as final and static does not help.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the `if()` by using this trick:

```
private Runnable once;
private final static Runnable NOP = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public void method () {
    once = new Runnable () {
        public void run () {
            doTrick();
            once = NOP;
        }
    }

    for (...) {
        ...
        once.run();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work but it's a bit overkill isn't it? Rosdi's answer is much simpler/clearer.

Comment: @Tomas: To expand your horizon :-)

Comment: @vickirk: It is for such a simple case. As soon as the conditions become more complex and you need more than one "run once" per loop, this trick can become much more readable since you can extract code out of the loop at little cost.

Comment: Sorry, not convinced, if the code to go in the if is complicated then move it into a private method, if the logic became more complex then the op would need to refactor at that point, probably going down the strategy/template method route.  This way makes unit testing more complicated, and using a runnable would have developers trying to figure out where threading becomes invovled.

Comment: Clever. :) I worked on a code base in C that did something similar by shifting a pointer to a global `void nil()` method. Seems like the same idea!

Comment: Will look much nicer with lambda expressions nowadays. You don’t even need the `NOP`. Just `Runnable once = () -> { doTrick(); once = () -> {}; };`

Comment: @Holger: With Java 8+, I would create a helper type which accepts a `Runnable` and hides the mess inside.

Answer (score 6):

**Another overkill solution:**

Depending on what you want to do, it might be possible to use a static initialization block.

```
public class YourKlass{
    public void yourMethod(){

        DoTrick trick; 

        for( int i = 0; condition; i++){
            // ... (1)
            trick = new DoTrick(); // or any kind of accessing DoTrick
            // ... (2)
        }

    } 
}

public class DoTrick{
    static{
        // Whatever should be executed only once 
    }
}
```

**Simple solution:**

Or, instead you just want to execute the first part outside of the loop:

```
int i = 0;
if( condition ){
    // ... (1)
    // do trick
    // ... (2)
}
for(i = 1; condition; i++){
    // ... (1)
    // ... (2)
}
```

Comment: -1 First solution is overkill, second solution is not IN the loop.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the break keyword is what you need? After running you method call break; I am sorry its not 100% clear what you mean from your question.

Have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) from the sun docs

Comment: A break would end the for-loop immediately. As the loop contains more code, than only the method-call, I assume a break isn't intended.

Answer (score 1):

my sample from my app:

```
boolean alreadyExecuted = false;
```

then :

```
private void startMyService() {

    if(!alreadyExecuted) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //Do something after 4 seconds
              context.startService(new Intent(context, myService.class));
              alreadyExecuted = true;
          }
        }, 4000);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to do something slight more complex. In a multi-threaded environment ensure that the methods is run only one (which is solved by Hover Ruan's answer above), but also block any thread so none return until the method is done.

My solution is to use a Semaphore to do the blocking.

```
public class Once implements Runnable {
    private static Semaphore signal = new Semaphore(1,true);
    private static boolean done=false;  

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(done)
            return;
        signal.acquireUninterruptibly();
        if(done) {
            signal.release();
            return;
        }
        doTrick(); // actually run the task
        done=true;
        signal.release();
        return;
    }

    static int result; // Result of running the task
    static int count;  // number of times its been called

    /**
     * The task we only want to run once
     */
    public void doTrick() {
        ++count;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
            result += rnd.nextInt(100);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // just to ensure all thread start
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for(int i=0;i<5;++i) { // multiple instances
            final Once task = new Once();
            for(int j=0;j<5;++j) { // multiple calls of same instance
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    task.run();
                    System.out.println("Result "+Once.result+" count "+Once.count);
                } );
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

The program should pause, waiting until the first thread has finished, then all other threads should finish printing the result stored from the first run.

Answer (score 1):

or by using **Shared Preferences**:

```
    sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


isFirstRun = sharedpref.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);

if (isFirstRun)
{

    // Do your unique code magic here

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
    editor.commit();
}else{
    //this will repeat everytime 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example way. Just use "new Getlineonce();"

```
class Getlineonce {
    static int[] linesRun = new int[0];

    public Getlineonce() {
        boolean lineRan = false;
        int line = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
        for(int i = 0; i < linesRun.length; i++) {
            if(line == linesRun[i]) {
                lineRan = true; //Dont print
            }
        }

        if(!lineRan) {
            add(line);
            System.out.println(line + " ran!");
        }

    }

    public void add(int line) {
        int newSize = linesRun.length+1;
        int[] linesRunBuff = new int[newSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < newSize-1; i++) {
            linesRunBuff[i] = linesRun[i];
        }
        linesRunBuff[newSize-1] = line;
        linesRun = linesRunBuff;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the perfect solution was...

```
 public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private static boolean splash = false;

    if (!splash){
        runSplash();
    }

    private void runSplash(){
        MainActivity.splash = true;
    }
 }
```

Defined my variable as private static and use the access via class.variable in my function :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, this will be called only once when the app is being installed for the first time on the user's device. Use SharedPreferences this will help us to remember that this method has already been called so it will not re-call it again when the app is killed or even if the device was turned off. (But keep in mind that when the user un-stall and then re-install the app the method will be called again)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean alreadyExecuted = false; // Use private static boolean

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // Use SharedPreferences
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("onlyonce", false)) {

            startMyService(); // Method to be called only once as long as the app wont be un-stalled but there is 
                              // no problem if the app will be killed or the device being turned off.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("onlyonce", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    private void startMyService() {

        if (!alreadyExecuted) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    alreadyExecuted = true;
                }
            }, 4000);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my brother

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class RemoveDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        originalList.add("foo");
        originalList.add("bar");
        originalList.add("bat");
        originalList.add("baz");
        originalList.add("bar");
        originalList.add("bar");
        String str="bar";
        ArrayList<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // adding duplicates to duplicateList
        for(String currentString : originalList) {
        if(currentString.startsWith(str)) {
                duplicateList.add(currentString);
            }
        }
        // removing duplicates in duplicatesList
        for(String removeString : duplicateList) {
            originalList.remove(removeString);
        }
        // finally adding duplicateElement
        originalList.add(str);

        for(String currEntry : originalList) {
            System.out.println(currEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?