# Java - make a method run only ONCE upon initial startup

Tags: java, methods

I'm working on a program that will include a method startup() for user configuration purposes. I only want this method to run once, upon initial startup of the program. how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Call it from main ()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is is possible to make a method execute only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665993/is-is-possible-to-make-a-method-execute-only-once)

Comment: please be clear initial startup means you want to run the function at the time program runs for the first time on the host or it means everytime it is executed

Answer (score 1):

You can use *static initializer* block.

```
public class MyClass {
static {
 // code to be executed once on startup
 }
}
```

Such static initializer blocks are executed when the class is loaded, even before `constructor` or `main` method is called.

You can have any number of these blocks and they will be executed in the order they appear in the code.